# Queue theory: how to recognize Agents in data?

Tags: python, networking, queue

I'm dealing with the [queueing-tool](https://queueing-tool.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for stimulate a one-node M/D/1 system where requests arrive with the arrival time defined as follows:

`def slow_arr(t): return t + random.expovariate(1.5)`

and service time:

`def ser(t): return t + 0.5`

During the simulation I need to simulate the arrival of additional requests that have lower arrival time:

`def fast_arr(t): return t + random.expovariate(0.15)`

From what I got from the docs, I defined two Agents (requests) as follows:

```
ag_slow = qt.Agent(
    agent_id = (1, 1),   # edge 1, agent 1
    arrival_f = slow_arr,
)

ag_fast = qt.Agent(
    agent_id = (1, 2),
    arrival_f = fast_arr
)
```

and the queue (which is only one in my simulation):

```
q = qt.QueueServer(
    num_servers = 1,
    collect_data = True,
    service_f = ser,
)
```

Now, I injected the first Agent into the server and simulate 10 events and checked the data (just in case)

```
q.set_active()  # accept agents
ag_slow.queue_action(queue=q)
q.simulate(n=10)
q.fetch_data()
```

Everything seems right.
Then I injected the second Agent (the requests with lower arrival time):

```
ag_fast.queue_action(queue=q)
q.simulate(n=10)
```

Then I port the data into a dataframe and that's the result:

| **id** | **arrival** | **service** | **departure** | **num_queued** | **num_total** | **q_id** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.967303 | 1.967303 | 2.467303 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2.093401 | 2.467303 | 2.967303 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 5.400844 | 5.400844 | 5.900844 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 5.765601 | 5.900844 | 6.400844 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 |
| 4 | 8.493998 | 8.493998 | 8.993998 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 9.035278 | 9.035278 | 9.535278 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 6 | 9.874867 | 9.874867 | 10.374867 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 10.542173 | 10.542173 | 11.042173 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 8 | 11.993661 | 11.993661 | 12.493661 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 9 | 13.107135 | 13.107135 | 0.000000 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 10 | 13.565815 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 |

Now I have two questions (or more?).
First of all, is the way I simulate the network okay? (please don't roast me).

Second, is there a way to get the info about the agents? (like, "is this an agent from those with lower arrival time?"). Maybe should be implemented such a thing? Like a label.

Thanks for the help.